# Validate inputs with a certain name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I want to get the inputs inside my form that has a name starting with **this_form_**. I have a loop creating my inputs so I don't know how many they are. And I have other inputs in the form that's not supposed to be validated.

This is how I create my forms:

```
<input type="text" name="this_form_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="" />
```

As I can delete specific inputs the names that I want to fetch can be this_form_100, this_form_101, this_form_102 and this_form_110

I can fetch the input value manually by doing the following:

```
document.forms['options-form']['this_form_100'].value
```

I just need a dynamic way to do this.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using [HTML5 form validation?](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#validation)

Comment: @MattBall: what about old IE?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy (1) I find it _very_ hard to care about any version of IE and (2) shims can fix that.

Comment: Because I don't want the form to get submitted if it's not validated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

complement your `input` tags with a css class. thereafter you can select the relevant set using `getElementsByClassName` ( docs cf. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName) ).

you might wish to employ [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/), a free and high quality js framework offering neat methods to handle cases like yours while abstracting away most of the user agent peculiarities.

Comment: I gave the inputs a class called this_form and tried to fetch the values by executing this: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName('this_form').value;`. It's not returning anything.

Comment: the method returns an array you have to iterate over - the `value` attribute will only be defined on the individual array elements (ie. the individual dom nodes).